# Equivalent of scipy curve_fit in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I need to fit a curve on a big data set and I was wondering if there is some similar function in pySpark as in SciPy (`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`) where I can pass model function, independent variables and parameters.

I know about linear regression in pySpark, but I need to use some other non-linear function.

Could someone give some advice on how to implement it on my own?